# vlan on mac address

Tags: router, openwrt, vlan

I am not sure how to title this, so it might not be clear...

I currently have an openwrt on my router at home. This router connects all devices in the house except for my digicorder. The provider requires us to connect the digicorder directly on the router provided, so I cannot connect this to my own router.

The problem is that next to my digicorder I have my media player that should be able to connect to my lan network and my media server. The cable arives at the tv and splits with a simple switch to the digicorder and the media player.

When I connect this line directly to the providers router I cannot reach my own server. When I connect the line to my own router, I can no longer use my digicorder.

I was wondering if it is possible to connect this line to my own router and tell openwrt to connect the digicorder directly to the providers network.

I have added a schema of my current setup with the line to the tv connected to the providers router.
[image]

Can someone tell me how to do this?

My router is a `NETGEAR WNDR3700v2` with `OpenWrt Backfire 10.03.1 / LuCI 0.10.0 Release (0.10.0)`

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: What is the reason for having the second ("your") router?

Comment: Because every port on the providers router is a separate network. Plus I cannot control anything on the providers router.

Comment: What sort of configuration changes have you attempted on your router in order to get this working?

Comment: Honestly, I haven't found anything yet on how to do this. I have been looking on the openwrt wiki and forum, but I'm not realy an expert in networking...